# Avoid focusing text boxes having attribute readonly using .not selector

Tags: jquery, html

I have a HTML table with text fields. While hitting enter inside these text boxes, the focus is shifted to the next input which is not disabled or hidden. I'm using the following code to select those inputs:

```
var $focusable = $(focusable)
    .not(":disabled")
    .not(":hidden")
    .not("a[href]:empty");
```

This is working fine. My problem is that I want to skip focusing text boxes which have the attribute `readonly` too. I tried to add `.not(":readonly")` to the code but it returns an error:

> Unrecognized expression

How can I avoid text boxes having the `readonly` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `:readonly` selector. Instead you should use the attribute selector to get the readonly elements, like this:

```
var $focusable = $(focusable).not('[readonly], :disabled, :hidden, a[href]:empty");
```

Note that I merged all the selectors in to a single method call.